# Dialog box hiding behind radsidedrawer in nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLWhp.png)The Dialog box is hiding behind the radsidedrawer in nativescript.

```
dialogs.alert({
    title: "Your title",
    message: "Your message",
    okButtonText: "Your button text"
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Dialog closed!");
});
```

Comment: This is happening only for IOS

Comment: Use 'showOverNavigation="true" ' in 'RadSideDrawer' tag

Comment: This is not working , and it is working fine in nativescript4.0